# Obtener valor de segunda tabla MySQL basandose en fecha más reciente

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo un gran problema, por más que le busco no encuentro el SQL adecuado para unir dos tablas, en la primera se encuentran los empleados, en la segunda los lugares que han visitado, el objetivo es crear una lista con todos los empleados y el último lugar que visitaron y la fecha. Anexo imagenes de mis tablas, ojalá me puedan ayudar, ya estoy perdiendo la cabeza con esta situación.

intente utilizar el siguiente Query, obtuve lo que necesitaba, pero al probarlo en tablas grandes (3000 empleados) tardó demasiado ya que son muchas subconsultas:

```
SELECT tblempleados.id as 'idEmp', tblempleados.Nombre as 'NombreEmpleado',
(select tblmovimientos.Id from bd_secjo.tblmovimientos where
 tblmovimientos.IdEmpleado = idEmp order by tblmovimientos.FechaMovimiento desc 
limit 1) as 'IdUltimoMov', (select tblmovimientos.Area from 
bd_secjo.tblmovimientos where tblmovimientos.Id = IdUltimoMov) as 'Area', 
(select tblmovimientos.FechaMovimiento from bd_secjo.tblmovimientos where 
tblmovimientos.Id = IdUltimoMov) as 'Fecha' from bd_secjo.tblempleados
```

[image: Tabla empleados]

[image: Tabla movimientos]

[image: Tabla como necesito que quede]

Comment: Ya probaste usando Join?

Comment: Por favor, agrega el query que hayas intentado que fallo. ( o si fueron varios tambien)

Comment: Ya, pero el detalle es que el id de la tabla de movimientos no corresponden a ningun id de la tabla de empleados, en si es una tabla cambiante y el objetivo es obtener los datos del movimiento más reciente para cada empleado.

Comment: Presiona el boton [edit] y agrega lo que intentaste en la pregunta. lo que estas pidiendo se puede hacer

Comment: Utilicé ese Query, y funcionó el problema es que son muchas subconsultas, y al probarlo en tablas grandes fué muy lenta la consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esta consulta. Yo la ejecuté en un ambiente de pruebas y funciona. Para resumir le puse tb1 a tblempleados y tb2 a la otra tabla, la reemplazas por tus valores.

```
SELECT tb1.Id AS idEmp, tb1.Nombre AS NombreEmpleado, 
tb2.IdEmpleado AS IdUltimoMov, tb2.Area, tb2.FechaMovimiento AS Fecha 
FROM tb2 
INNER JOIN tb1 ON tb1.Id=tb2.IDEmpleado 
WHERE tb2.FechaMovimiento IN (SELECT MAX(FechaMovimiento) FROM tb2 GROUP BY IdEmpleado);
```

Comment: Amigo me has sacado de un apuro enorme como no tienes idea. Te lo agradezco de verdad que había buscado en todos lados he intentado infinidad de formas pero nunca lo habría logrado solo, voy a ponerme a estudiar tu Query para entender como funciona al cien. Muchas gracias.